# How use regex operator 'or' in javascript with parenthesis?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find those strings:

'555-555-5555'

'(555)555-5555'

I wrote:

```
number = '(555)555-5555'
regex =   ((/^\d{3,3}-\d{3,3}-\d{4,4}$/) | (/^\(\d{3,3}\)\d{3,3}-\d{4,4}$/))
let s =  number.match(regex)
```

But it returns 'null'. I don't understand, how use operator 'or' in regex here?

Comment: If you're trying to validate phone numbers, regex is generally the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Try `console.log(regex)`. You are using the [Bitwise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) (`|`) operator and not [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use to place the `/` delimiters outside of the regex. you can also simplify the quantifiers `{3,3}` by writing simply `{3}`.

This should give you the expected result

```
/^(?:\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{4})$/gm
```